# need to fill my listbox with first index of each line in a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, text, listbox, duplicates

I'm struggling with what seemed to be a fairly easy task at first.
I am trying to populate my `listbox` with the first index of each line in my  text file. Here is my code, what I'm currently getting is the first index of the first line duplicated 6 times.

```
int Counter = 0;
StreamReader supReader = new StreamReader(@"data\Suppliers.txt", true);
while (!supReader.EndOfStream)
{
     string line = supReader.ReadLine();
     string[] tokens = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
     foreach (string s in tokens)
     {
          if (listsup.Items.Contains(tokens) == false)
          {
                listsup.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
                Counter++;
          }

      }

}
supReader.Close();
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: CSharp, sorry. Didn't say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to get the whole affair to work, I changed my code to a bit more practical approach:

```
Supfile = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "data\\Suppliers.txt";

        try
        {
            StreamReader inputFile;
            inputFile = File.OpenText(Supfile);

            string lines;

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                lines = inputFile.ReadLine();
                string[] tokens = lines.Split(',');
                if (!listsup.Items.Contains(tokens))
                {
                    listsup.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
                }
                else { listsup.Update(); }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

This works perfectly, had to add `listsup.Items.Clear();`to the top to ensure it doesnt duplicate the list in the listbox.